# Problem locating a file in a jar file

Tags: java, apache, ant, jar

I am a Apache Ant novice and I have created a Java application that contains, among many files, a sys.properties file. The location of this file is in the root and in order to be called the string "sys.properties" in the code is used to locate this file. It does working perfectly.

Now I have created with Apache Ant a build file which creates a jar file out of the application. In the code I have used

```
<filelist dir="${basedir}" files="sys.properties"/>
```

which indeed places the new file in the root of the jar file when this jar file is created.

When I run via command line:

```
java -classpath C:\tmp\APP;doddle.jar; doddle.home.start
```

the jar application seems to look for the sys.properties but it can't find it (the *doddle.home.start* class calls the sys.properties).

Any idea where the problem may be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you try to find the file? It works if you use [ClassLoader.findResource(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResource(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `sys.properties` is no longer a file, it's a jar entry.

You can access it as an [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) by [`SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/sys.properties")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) (see [the I/O tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) on how to handle streams)

Comment: So I should put the sys.properties out of the jar and referencing when I call it via command line?

     I.E. java -classpath C:\tmp\APP;doddle.jar;sys.properties doddle.home.start

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information about how you are trying to reference the file.  What path are you using?  If you are trying to open "sys.properties" you can try referencing "/sys.properties", which should open the file from the root of the jar file.